# BatchUpdateException duplicate key value violates unique constraint

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I have to swap properties of different rows of same table.
There is one column "reference_id" which have a **unique** constraint in DB.

**CODE:**

**Class A-**

```
@Override
@Transactional
@ResponseBody
@RequestMapping(value = "/cust/{fromCustId}/{toCustId}/swapCusts", method = { RequestMethod.PUT })
public void swapContents(@PathVariable("fromCustId") final long fromCustId, @PathVariable("toCustId") final long toCustId) throws InvalidCustException
{           
    custService.swapContents(fromCustId, toCustId);     
}
```

**Class B-**

```
 @Override
          public void swapContents(long fromCustId, long toCustId) throws InvalidCustException {
           try {
            CustEntity fromCustEntity = custManager.findByPrimaryKey(fromCustId);
            CustEntity toCustEntity = custManager.findByPrimaryKey(toCustId);

            if (null == fromCustEntity || null == toCustEntity) {
             throw new InvalidCustException("Either fromCustId=[" + fromCustId + "] or toCustId=[" + toCustId + "] is invalid");
            }

            String fromCust_RefId = fromCustEntity.getReferenceId();
            String fromCust_Password = fromCustEntity.getPassword();

            String toCust_RefId = toCustEntity.getReferenceId();
            toCustEntity.setReferenceId("##" + toCust_RefId);
            custManager.merge(toCustEntity);

            fromCustEntity.setReferenceId(toCust_RefId);
            fromCustEntity.setPassword(toCustEntity.getPassword());


            toCustEntity.setReferenceId(fromCust_RefId);
            toCustEntity.setPassword(fromCust_Password);

            custManager.merge(fromCustEntity);
            custManager.merge(toCustEntity);

           } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e.getMessage(), e);
           }
          }
```

**Exception trace:**

```
   2016-11-24 15:14:26,772 WARN  [http-nio-8093-exec-8] or.hi.en.jd.sp.SqlExceptionHelper (SqlExceptionHelper.java:144) - SQL Error: 0, SQLState: null 2016-11-24 15:14:26,774 ERROR [http-nio-8093-exec-8] or.hi.en.jd.sp.SqlExceptionHelper (SqlExceptionHelper.java:146) - PerfPreparedStatement.executeBatch - update cust set  password='30ca904c-f720-4994-9e1a-dc5153c1cd85', reference_id='3355efa8-53df-4220-be32-752ce9a54645', cust_uuid=? where cust_id=82737521 2016-11-24 15:14:26,780 ERROR [http-nio-8093-exec-8] or.hi.en.jd.ba.in.BatchingBatch (BatchingBatch.java:141) - HHH000315: Exception executing batch [could not execute batch] 2016-11-24 15:14:26,822 WARN  [http-nio-8093-exec-8] co.gr.en.pu.ut.CommonExceptionConverterLogic (CommonExceptionConverterLogic.java:139) - org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not execute batch for User ID: 805, Request ID: b9167f59-87ee-498e-8aba-f505d2dea195, clientIP: 10.201.141.120 method: PUT uri: /custApi/services/cust/82737521/82737513/swapCusts, Request Parameters: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "tuc_cust_1"   Detail: Key (reference_id)=(41e24e58-a108-4f12-9b6b-4250a7a379e5) already exists.      
   at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2157)      
   at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:1886) [wrapped] java.sql.BatchUpdateException: Batch entry 0 update cust set password='530a32c1-eba5-4de8-8e85-97d3af62c331', reference_id='41e24e58-a108-4f12-9b6b-4250a7a379e5', cust_uuid=? where cust_id=82737513 was aborted.  Call getNextException to see the cause.      
   at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement$BatchResultHandler.handleError(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:2746)      
   at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:1887)      
   at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:405)      
   at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.executeBatch(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:2893)      
   at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewProxyPreparedStatement.executeBatch(NewProxyPreparedStatement.java:1723) [wrapped] java.sql.SQLException: PerfPreparedStatement.executeBatch - update cust set password='30ca904c-f720-4994-9e1a-dc5153c1cd83', reference_id='3355efa8-53df-4220-be32-752ce9a54645', cust_uuid=? where cust_id=82737521
```

Comment: Batch Update is causing unique constraint exception. So even though I am purposely prepending "##" to the referenceId so that it will be unique but that also is not working. Is there something like "Separate Transactions for each merge query" so that the batch update will not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try flushing your entity manager between merges.